# function to find minimum number greater than zero from rows of a array and store into a list

Tags: python, numpy

I want to find out minimum number from the rows of 9x9 array `A` and store in a list `m`. But I want to exclude zero. The program that I made is returning zero as minimum.

```
m = []
def find (L):
    for i in range(len(L)):
            m.append(A[L[i]].min()) 

c = [2,3,4,5,6];
find(c)
print m
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a NumPy solution -

```
np.where(a>0,a,a.max()).min(1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [45]: a
Out[45]: 
array([[0, 4, 6, 6, 1],
       [3, 1, 5, 0, 0],
       [6, 3, 6, 0, 0],
       [0, 6, 3, 5, 2]])

In [46]: np.where(a>0,a,a.max()).min(1)
Out[46]: array([1, 1, 3, 2])
```

If you want to perform this operation along selected rows only specified by row indices in `L` -

```
def find(a,L): 
    return np.where(a[L]>0,a[L],a.max()).min(1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [62]: a
Out[62]: 
array([[0, 4, 6, 6, 1],
       [3, 1, 5, 0, 0],
       [6, 3, 6, 0, 0],
       [0, 6, 3, 5, 2]])

In [63]: L = [2,3]

In [64]: find(a,L)
Out[64]: array([3, 2])
```

Comment: QA wants minima in only some rows, specified by `L`

Comment: yes I want minima only for rows specified in **L**.. how to use this code in this case?

Comment: @vidyanair As shown in the sample run : `np.where(a[L]>0,a[L],a.max()).min(1)`?

Comment: m getting output like this `array([13, 14,  3, 72,  4]), array([13, 14,  3, 72,  4]), array([13, 14,  3, 72,  4]), array([13, 14,  3, 72,  4]), array([13, 14,  3, 72,  4])]` ....previously it was like this `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

Comment: @vidyanair You are supposed to use : `def find(a,L): return np.where(a[L]>0,a[L],a.max()).min(1)`, so skip the loop part. I am guessing you are seeing the wrong output, because you are using the proposed code with `np.where` inside the loop, which is not intended.

Comment: tried above code..not showing anything at output even though not showing any error.

Comment: @vidyanair Could be an indentation issue with copying. Try the function I have just posted in my post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130108/discussion-between-vidya-nair-and-divakar).

Comment: @vidyanair Curious if you were able to sort out the return issue?

Comment: No..i used print instead